# Constructing numerical examples of the Klein 4 group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I am trying to find a general way to generate numerical examples of the Klein 4 group, $V$.

So far I understand that $V$ arises as a subgroup of the unit group of some ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and I found it seems to be necessary to use the theorem 'If $n=n_1n_2...n_k$ with each $n_j$ relatively prime then $\mathbb{Z}^\times_n=\mathbb{Z}^\times_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}^\times_{n_2}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}^\times_{n_k}$'.

I think that all I need is to find unit groups with 2 elements of order 2, I am unsure how to proceed with this.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_8^×\cong V.$  Moreover,  $\Bbb Z_{2^n}^×\cong \Bbb Z_{2^{n-2}}×\Bbb Z_2.$

Comment: @insomesense Ok so I understand this and I know a few specific constructions but I'd like a way to construct $V$ more generally, I know that for example there exists a construction in modulo 24 so I'd like to know for which $n$ the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ contains $V$.

Comment: Well,  you can take cross products with cyclic groups,  like $\Bbb Z_3,$ and use the fact you mentioned,  about the group of units functor respecting products.

Comment: It arises in any odd composite number that is not a prime power, or any even composite number that is divisible by $4$ and some oddrime, since if $p$ and $q$, $p\neq q$ are odd primes dividing $n$, then the units modulo $n$ contain direct factors isomorphic to $C_{(p-1)p^k}$ and to $C_{(q-1)q^r}$ for some $k,r\geq0$, and both of those contain cyclic subgroups of order $2$. Almost every composite number will, except those of the form $2p^r$ for odd prime $p$, and prime powers.